# Downloading a PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I am trying to download a .pdf file which opens up in an IE Web browser.  Here is my code:

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
(ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, _
ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Sub DownPDF()

Dim sUrl As String
Dim sPath As String

sPath = "C:\Users\adhil\Documents"
sUrl = "http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2010/HOW01.Waller.pdf"

Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, sUrl, sPath, 0, 0)
If Ret = 0 Then
    Debug.Print sUrl & " downloaded to " & sPath
Else
    Debug.Print sUrl & " not downloaded"
End If

End Sub
```

However, I am unable to get the file downloaded although response says so.

Can anyone assist me?

Answer (score 1):

The function expects the parameter `szFileName` to be a fullpath name of a file, not a folder.
Try with this:

```
sPath = "C:\Users\adhil\Documents\HOW01.Waller.pdf"
```

I worked with me, while it did not work when the destination file name was omitted.